# Win32 Window Menu is appearing along left side instead of across top of window

Tags: c++, winapi, menu

I think I may be using a wrong window style or something or maybe just adding the menu to the window incorrectly.  I'll post a link to an image here so you can see what I mean about the menu not diplaying correctly:

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4828/wtfmenu.jpg

And here's a link to the code that creates the menu and the window:

http://pastebin.com/CBrSVXUD

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and dumb in the labyrinth of styles, settings and etc that are part and parcel for the Win32 API.  Has anyone seen this before and know what I'm doing wrong?  I just want a 'normal' menu bar along the top, snug against the title bar.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MF_MENUBREAK` flag you use when adding the popups causes this—that flag is only required if you want the menu item to appear on a new line in the menu bar. Take out both of the `MF_MENUBREAK` flags and all will be well.

Comment: Excellent.  That's got it.  Thank you very much.  It's odd that the flag was there.  I generated the menu code using a window design utility.  I'll have to keep an eye on that in the future.  Thank you again.  :)